# CREATE FUNCTION inside BEGIN TRY and END TRY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to use CREATE FUNCTION in a block that will "swallow" errors, but this

```
BEGIN TRY

CREATE FUNCTION test (@ID int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(2 * @ID)
END


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

results in

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'FUNCTION'. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7 Must declare the scalar
> variable "@ID".

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many DDL statements must either start a batch or be the only statement in a batch.  So the general solution is to use dynamic SQL.  EG

I want to use CREATE FUNCTION in a block that will "swallow" errors, but this

```
BEGIN TRY

exec('
CREATE FUNCTION test (@ID int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(2 * @ID)
END
')

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: Can I escape ':s in the string?

Comment: `'` is escaped in TSQL with `''`